# Extracting values from an XML column in PostgreSQL without libxml

Tags: xml, postgresql, common-table-expression

I am working on this system with psql 10 and libxml is not enabled. The table I am working on has two columns: session and trace. Following is a sample row:

```
session || trace
z9hG4bK6ee1f3b0-3a3a-ea11-9bc7-000c2974e021 || <schema method="syn"><tr><hop ip="10.13.37.212" delay="0.00" jitter="0"/><hop ip="10.13.37.1" delay="1.51" jitter="0"/><hop ip="192.168.103.38" delay="7.68" jitter="0"/></tr></schema>
```

It is meant to provide the stats on a hop-by-hop basis for a session. The sample row has three hops. I have been looking for a way to query this table to get the following result:

```
session || hop_number || hop_ip || delay || jitter
z9hG4bK6ee1f3b0-3a3a-ea11-9bc7-000c2974e021 || 1 || 10.13.37.212 || 0.00 || 0
z9hG4bK6ee1f3b0-3a3a-ea11-9bc7-000c2974e021 || 2 || 10.13.37.1 || 1.51 || 0
z9hG4bK6ee1f3b0-3a3a-ea11-9bc7-000c2974e021 || 3 || 192.168.103.38 || 7.68 || 0
```

Since I am missing the xml library, can someone please point me in the right direction? I was thinking maybe I can use recursive CTE with substrings for this  but I could not find a good example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `hop_number` ?

Comment: hop_number is not included in the raw original data. So I need to inject it as a new column when parsing happens. Basically, an incremental value can be assigned to each IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your needs ? ([Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rh6TYfkfFsPDRNoPBhxRG7/0))

```
select session,xmltable.* 
from sessions,
xmltable('//schema/tr/hop'
         passing trace
         columns hop_number for ordinality, hop_ip text path '@ip', delay numeric path '@delay', jitter int path '@jitter'
        );
```

Comment: db=# select "session",xmltable.*
from "sessions",
xmltable('/schema/tr/hop'
         passing trace
         columns hop_number for ordinality, hop_ip text path '@ip', delay numeric path '@delay', jitter int path '@jitter'
        );
ERROR:  column "trace" does not exist
LINE 4:          passing trace


Thank you very much @Philippe I think I am missing something here. Should I be modifying a part of what you sent based on my table?

Comment: What is the name of the column containing your xml value ?

Comment: "TRACEROUTE_XML".. Also, I was wondering if I will need libxml in order to execute this query. Because I don't have it.

Comment: Sorry, yes i just read the documentation and it needs postgresql to be built with libxml

Comment: no worries. Thanks for taking the time to help anyway.

Comment: Has the XML always the same structure ?

Comment: Yes. Well, the number of lines changes depending on how many hops there are; but the structure remains.